# Get data for div based on select value with ajax

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I am currently stuck with getting data for a div on the same page based on the selected value from a dropdown.

I have a dropdown where the user can select a value. The dropdown takes the data from the CourseOverview-Model. Based on the selection, the div in the second part of the page should be filled in also with data from the CourseOverview-Model. In my code, the console.log shows the value I choose. But I am stuck with getting the connection to the whole data so that the second part of the page gets filled out. Any help is appreciated.

The goal is to create an individual scorecard with the prefilled table in the next step.

My html looks like this:

```
<!--Dropdown-->
<div class="container">
        <select id="choosecourse">
            <option value="">Select course</option>
            {% for course in courses %} 
            <option>{{ course.name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
</div>

<!--Second part of the page which should be filled in based on the selection-->
<div class="container">
        <h5>{{ id.name }}</h5>
</div>
<div class="container">
        <table class="table input-width">
            <tr>
                <td>Holes:</td>
                <td>{{ id.holes }}</td>
                <td>Par:</td>
                <td>{{ id.par }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Your handicap:</td>
                <td>{{ user.handicap }}</td>
                <td>Extra strokes:</td>
                <td><input type="number" min="0"></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

My javascript looks like this:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#choosecourse').change(function(){
                var name = document.getElementById("choosecourse").value;
                console.log(name)
                });
            });
</script>
```

My views.py looks like this:

```
def add_score(request):
        courses = CourseOverview.objects.all()
        return render(request, "mrc/add_score.html", {
            "courses": courses
        })
```

And these are both necessary models from models.py:

```
class CourseOverview(models.Model):
    course_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    par = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    holes = models.PositiveIntegerField()


class Course(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey("CourseOverview", on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="course")
    hole = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    holepar = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    holehcpi = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

**EDIT**
I tried for example the following:

```
<div class="container">
        <select id="choosecourse">
            <option value="">Select course</option>
            {% for course in courses %} 
            <option>{{ course.name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
</div>

<!--Second part of the page which should be filled in based on the selection-->
<div class="container">
        <h5 id="name"></h5>
</div>
<div class="container">
        <table class="table input-width">
            <tr>
                <td>Holes:</td>
                <td id="holes"></td>
                <td>Par:</td>
                <td id="par"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Your handicap:</td>
                <td>{{ user.handicap }}</td>
                <td>Extra strokes:</td>
                <td><input type="number" min="0"></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#choosecourse').change(function(){
                var name = document.getElementById("choosecourse").value;
                fetch("mrc/add_score.html", {
                    method: "PUT",
                headers:{
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', 
                },
            })
            .then(response => {
                return response.json()
            })
            .then(data => {
                document.querySelector('#name').innerhtml = id.name
                document.querySelector('#holes').innerhtml = id.holes
                document.querySelector('#par').innerhtml = id.par
            })})})
```

And views.py:

```
def add_score(request):
    if request.method == "PUT":
        data = CourseOverview.objects.all()
        return JsonResponse(data)
    else:
        courses = CourseOverview.objects.all()
        return render(request, "mrc/add_score.html", {
            "courses": courses
        })
```

Comment: You aren't providing a `value` attribute for the `<option>` elements. Beyond that please explain in more detail where you are stuck. Where is data coming from to fill in this table when you do make a selection?

Comment: I have specified my post. Even though the option elements do not have a value attribute, the console.log(name) part of my code shows the chosen option. So this is working. The data is coming from my CourseOverview-Model (see my views.py). I am stuck with getting the right data also from the CourseOverview-Model to fill out the table. I have tried different ajax-get and put solutions, but did not get anything to work.

Comment: Show us your ajax attempts. SO isn't a free code writing service . It should be very easy to find lots of tutorials on using ajax

Comment: I have edited my post and added one of the things I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution for my problem. As my page has already all information it needs, I added a for-loop for all divs containing the data I want and hide them.

In the next step I added some javascript to display the div that was chosen over the dropdown and hide the others.

Here is the corresponding code. Hope this helps someone with a similar problem.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <select id="choosecourse">
            <option value="">Select course</option>
            {% for course in courses %} 
            <option>{{ course.name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
</div>

<!--Second part of the page which should be filled in based on the selection-->
<div class="container">
        <h5 id="name"></h5>
</div>
<div class="container">
        {% for course in courses %}
        <div style="display: none;" class="hidethem" data-name="{{ course.name }}">
            <div><h5 id=>{{ course.name }}</h5></div>
            <div><table class="table input-width">
                <tr>
                    <td>Holes:</td><td>{{ course.holes }}</td>
                    <td>Par:</td><td>{{ course.par }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Your handicap:</td><td>{{ user.handicap }}</td>
                    <td>Extra strokes:</td><td><input type="number" min="0"></td>
                </tr>
            </table></div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
</div>
```

My javascript looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#choosecourse').change(function(){
                let name = document.getElementById("choosecourse").value;
                console.log(name);
                $(".hidethem").hide();
                document.querySelector("[data-name=" + CSS.escape(name) + "]").style.display = 'block';
                });
            });
```

Nevertheless thanks for the chance to discuss problems here!